# How to install find / internal positiong

Tags: linux, go, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to install the find server, the internal positioning (https://github.com/schollz/find)  (https://www.internalpositioning.com/) software that has a server for on the Raspberry Pi (3).

The install works by using golang, and I cannot quite figure out how to make go(lang) install the find package. The directions given on the otherwise helpful install page (https://www.internalpositioning.com/server/) are to install go (which I have done by $ sudo apt-get install golang) and that indeed does tell me that I have go version go1.7.4 linux/arm (command `$ go version`).

Additionally I have set the root paths so that the Raspberry Pi actually knows where to find go:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOTH/bin
```

We then proceed with the actual commands to install find (internal positioning software server) by cloning it from github and installing it with go(lang); via the following commands.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/schollz/find.git    
$ cd find    
$ go get ./...
$ go build
```

I cannot get the '/find $ go get ./...' command to work with whatever parameters I put in. Clearly the command needs input parameters / directories but none of the input paths I have tried seem to work, and I cannot figure out which one it wants from googling the issue or indeed looking it up on stackoverflow.

Running '/find $ go get ./...' does not appear to give me any response from the raspberry pi; there is not message that it is doing something and the raspberry pi cpu percentage stays low; after 5 - 10 minutes I get:

```
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/foo/vendored /home/pi/go/src/github.com/foo/vendored
Cloning into '/home/pi/go/src/github.com/foo/vendored'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
package github.com/foo/vendored: exit status 128
Password:
```

which does not help me a whole lot either. Running it by pointing golang towards the go github location also does not yield anything promising:

```
/find $ go get https://github.com/schollz/find.git   
package https:/github.com/schollz/find.git: "https://" not allowed in import path
```

nor does

```
 /find $ go get /home/pi./find
package /home/pi./find: unrecognized import path "/home/pi./find" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

I have no clue what go wants of me; anyone able to shed a light?

EDIT: I seem to have fixed the issue where the gopath is not being found correctly: rather than using `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` I have used `GOPATH=$HOME/go`; no idea why that fixes things.

I now get the error when I use the command `$ go get ./...`

```
find $ go get ./...
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/foo/vendored /home/pi/go/src/github.com/foo/vendored
Cloning into '/home/pi/go/src/github.com/foo/vendored'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
package github.com/foo/vendored: exit status 128
Password:
```

Indicating I would need to login: however I cannot seem to make this happen either.

Answer (score 0):

go get disable "terminal prompt" by default. This can be changed by set the env of git:

```
env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get github.com/schollz/find/...
```